# Double/ Long to BigInteger

Tags: java, math, double, long-integer, biginteger

I'm trying to make a program that finds 2 to the power of the large integer 'n'.

I get the error that double cannot be converted to BigInteger. So I was wondering can double/long be converted to BigInteger?

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargePow2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("n = ?");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("2^" + n + " is \n" + pow2(n));
    }

    public static BigInteger pow2(long n){
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        result = Math.pow(n, 2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `result` is a `BigInteger` and `Math.pow(...)` returns a double, that's why `result = Math.pow(n, 2);` does not work. Won't work with other primitives anyway... You have to use `BigInteger.pow(int n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to avoid the Math.pow() function because it returns the result as double, which is less accurate in case of very large numbers.

```
    public static BigInteger pow2(long n){
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n).pow(2);
    }
```

Comment: I tried using your way but instead of returning a very long result, it only shows a short one. For example 2^1000, I get 1000000

Comment: @JustTryingToCode: Your question asked for n\*\*2, **not** 2\*\*n

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah I didn't realise but I had it wrong and I changed it. Sorry about that

Comment: @JustTryingToCode: Ok, then just swap the "2" and the "n" in the return statement in this answer. But note that you are still limited by the amount of memory on your system. You won't be able to do this for `n` much larger than a regular 32-bit int.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it gives me an error of possible lossy conversion from long to int

Comment: @JustTryingToCode: Ah, that's right, the `pow()` argument has to be an int. For the reason I stated in my previous comment this is not much of a limitation. 2\*\*Integer.MAX_VALUE is already an enormous number that takes up a significant fraction of all the memory on a typical computer. If you need larger numbers you probably need to re-think your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the double to BigDecimal and then into a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger result = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(n, 2)).toBigInteger();
```

Comment: Two issues: Math.pow() does not work well with large numbers, and I think that matters here because you used BigInteger as result type. Also the conversion from BigDecimal to BigInteger is not needed. You can use the function ```bigInteger.pow()```.

Comment: This doesn't return the very long value that I needed, instead it returns about 16 numbers and then all 0s